# Is there anyway to have common sso for both facebook and google?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, ios6

Currently I am using Facebook single sign on for authentication and it works perfectly. I would like to add Google authentication as well. But if I allow the user to authenticate via Google, how would the user post on a Facebook wall without Facebook also authenticating them?

Please help me out, I am new to cross application development. Or please tell me if there is any alternative method. Any advice and guidance will help me and the users who have similar question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no common SSO for Google and Facebook. Your user must connect with Facebook in order to post on their Facebook wall.

Comment: SO if you have logged in via google login how would I get facebook Session id ?

Comment: You ask the user to connect again via Facebook (using the Facebook SDK - https://developers.facebook.com/android/).

Comment: No other way sir.If I allow user to verify if thy are exiting user in my server and then if he has to post on the wall he has to login via facebook again ? how do oter apps work ? is it the same Sir ?

Comment: If they authenticate to your service using only google, but they want to post to facebook, they MUST authenticate again with facebook. There's no other way.

Comment: OK cool.Same holds got vice-versa.Logged in via facebook and postinging on google+  ??

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but I suspect so.

Comment: I have tried sso login with facebook but I did  not get sso for google example for android/ios .Please can you share the link if you come across any ?